# Is there any alternative to <span>?

Tags: html, css

I already use `<span>` in my code via .js for bold text in my CMS for, let's say title inputs. Now I just want to add a blue background behind the title text as shown below but without  using  the background gets stretched.

I'd like my background to respond to text input length and this is the easiest way without scrambling the whole code. Is it possible?

```css
body {} img {
  width: 100%;
}
.h {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
.h span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00A0E8;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.square {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00A0E8;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="h"><span><b>I WANT</b> THIS</span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="h">
  <div class="square"><b>I GET</b> THIS</div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: So why don't you use the version that you want? What do you original code looks like?

Comment: check in some other browser....see here what you want.  https://jsfiddle.net/hyqdudt8/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block;` in `.square` class.

```css
body {} img {
  width: 100%;
}
.h {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
.h span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00A0E8;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.square {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00A0E8;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="h"><span><b>I WANT</b> THIS</span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="h">
  <div class="square"><b>I GET</b> THIS</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS attribute [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). You can set it to: `inline` or `inline-block`. Indeed, that's what `<span>` does by default

Answer (score 0):

[Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is useful to quickly specify inline content.

I found that it doesn't works well in combination of css transitions.

Here is an alternative list of html element that behave inline by default.

Most are made for text!

```
<a>
<abbr>
<acronym>
<audio> (if has visible controls)
<b>
<bdi>
<bdo>
<big>
<br>
<button>
<canvas>
<cite>
<code>
<data>
<datalist>
<del>
<dfn>
<em>
<embed>
<i>
<iframe>
<img>
<input>
<ins>
<kbd>
<label>
<map>
<mark>
<meter>
<noscript>
<object>
<output>
<picture>
<progress>
<q>
<ruby>
<s>
<samp>
<script>
<select>
<slot>
<small>
<span>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<svg>
<template>
<textarea>
<time>
<u>
<tt>
<var>
<video>
<wbr>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements